# S/MIME Library for Windows Phone SDK?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, smime

Is there any open source library which supports S/MIME encryption on windows phone?

The Silverlight library only supports a subset of the .NET library...

Answer (score 0):

You can still use any .Net library as long as it's not using anything platform specific.
Have a look on this thread:
[S/MIME libraries for .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127363/s-mime-libraries-for-net)

Comment: Silverlight and WP7 API are badly crippled, so most components won't work out of the box. Among things I can think of right now are lack of extensive charset support (we carry our own charset tables in SecureBlackbox) and limited cryptographic capabilities (and S/MIME is about cryptography).

Comment: Did you tried any of them? Why you are making your own charset tables when .NET is fully utf based?

Comment: The open source library http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41727/An-S-MIME-Library-for-Sending-Signed-and-Encrypted from the thread doesn't work on windows phone because of missing api parts in wp7.

Comment: Guys, can you confirm that you cant get any S/MIME in Silverlight working, so I'll make you one. I am expert in both apparently, and I got some resources already to make it.

Comment: @AndrewSmith you name yourself an expert in S/MIME and ask why charsets are needed. Quite strange ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a portable .NET S/MIME implementation (fully managed) that works on Windows, Linux, Mac, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

I don't have the WindowsPhone SDK so can't check that it compiles there, but I'll happily accept patches.

https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit